# How to solve the following bivariate recurrence?

Tags: pr.probability, recurrences

$$F(n,r) = (1-w(r))F(n-1, r) + w(r-1)F(n-1, r-1)$$
where $w(r)$ is monotonically non-increasing in $r$ and $0 \leq w(r) \leq 1$ with $0 \leq r$

Initial condition:
\begin{eqnarray}
F(0, r) & = & 0;\; \forall r \geq 0\\
F(k,0)  & = & (1-w(0))^k;\;  \forall k \geq 1\\
F(n, r) & = & 0;\; \forall r > n
\end{eqnarray}
There are several questions in math exchange/math overflow  bivariate recurrence but none of their answers solves this kind of relation so I'm posting it.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @katz not at all. I'm studying just out my interest

Comment: @Can you elaborate on what exactly your interests are?

Comment: While studying about the dynamic programming I found they basically use a look-up  table. I'm learning dp by solving different problems. Then being inspired by the Fibonacci series trying to solve recursions mathematically too.

Comment: Actually this is one of the examples of recurrences among the ones I'm trying to solve. If this is solved others I'll try accordingly

Comment: @katz any help?